# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "cities" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"cities"'::regclass ^

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, rails-activerecord

I am new to Sinatra and trying to create a post request which would add some data into "City" table in PGadmin. But, I am getting an error when trying to add it. The get request works fine, and posting static data on the post endpoint also works fine, but posting data doesn't I am not sure what's wrong since the migration and the model for city does exist. Here's the code:

city.rb

```
class City < UserDB
    validates_presence_of :name, :pin


    def as_json(options = {})
        super({only: [:city, :pin]})
    end
end
```

migration:

```
class CreateCity < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :city do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :pin
    end
  end
end


module Users
    module V1
        class CityController< LocalAPI::ApplicationBase
            before do
                content_type 'application/json'
            end
            get '/' do
                city=City.all
                if city
                    "city exists"
                else
                    "doesn't exist"
                end
            end
           
            post '/add' do
                params = JSON.parse request.body.read
                @name= params['name']
                @pin= params['pin']
                @city=City.new(name:@name,pin:@pin)
                
                if @city.save
                    return output(200, @city.as_json)
                else 
                    "cant create"
                end
            end
            
           

        end
    end
 end
```

I am trying to post the below content through postman:

```
{
    "name": "hamilton",
    "pin":"222"
}
```

Please note that the route is configured and it does work when I visit the url. Also have ran `db:migrate`

Comment: This is Sinatra, and not Rails, correct?

Comment: @tadman yes this is Sinatra

Comment: What does `params.inspect` return?

Comment: also in `return`: `JSON: return => @city`

Comment: @thiebo `{"name"=>"hamilton", "pin"=>1234}`. The params seem to be passing correctly, the issue might be while creating the entry in the db

Comment: the console shows the commands and what it registered in the DB. Anything?

Comment: try removing the validation for the moment ?

Comment: the error looks like the kind of one an incorrect polymorphic relation would throw.  Is UserDB a subclass of ActiveRecord?